# Den Gefühlen wird durch Mimik, Stimmlage und Gestik Ausdruck verliehen

Tags: grammatical-case

Dieser Satz steht im Erkundungen-Lösungsschlüsselbuch. Ich frage mich, warum das Verb hier **wird** statt **werden** ist, obwohl **das Gefühl** im Plural (Dativ) ist. 
Oder das ist einfach ein falscher Satz?

Comment: Bitte füge vor Satzzeichen keine Leerzeichen ein.

Comment: Ausdruck wird verliehen, also singular.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, bitte benutze Kommentare nicht für Antworten.

Comment: @Carsten: Das war nur eine Bemerkung, keine Antwort. Ein Antwort verlangt etwas mehr, m.E, und dafür hatte ich die Zeit nicht.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, ich bin in einer solchen Situation auch manchmal versucht, aber man sollte es trotzdem lassen. In dieser konkreten Situation frage ich mich natürlich auch, worum Du meinst, dass meine Antwort nicht ausreichend war.

Comment: @CarstenS: Meinte ich gar nicht. Ich finde deine Antwort ausgezeichnet.

Answer (score 5):

Das Verb richtet sich nach dem Subjekt. Was ist hier aber das Subjekt? Es kann nicht *den Gefühlen* sein, denn das ist Dativ, das hast Du ja schon geschrieben. Du hast vielleicht auch bemerkt, dass der Satz im Passiv steht. Das Subjekt ist *Ausdruck*, und es ist im Singular. Einfachere Beispiele mit dem gleichen Verb:

Aktiv:

> Der Präsident verleiht dem Lehrer einen Orden.

Passiv:

> Ein Orden wird dem Lehrer (vom Präsidenten) verliehen.

Oder in anderer Reihenfolge:

> Dem Lehrer wird ein Orden verliehen.

Das Subjekt ist immer noch *ein Orden*. Im Plural:

> Dem Lehrer werden zwei Orden verliehen.

Comment: Ist nicht *Ausdruck* das Subjekt?

Comment: Aha , jetzt ist es klar . Also , jemand oder man hat einer Sache etwas verleihen . Und ja , ich weiß schon , dass der Satz im Passiv steht . Der Aktivsatz lautet „ Mimik , Stimmlage und Gestik verleihen den Gefühlen Ausdruck “ . Vielen Dank für Ihre Antwort und schönen Tag noch .

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Du hast recht, Danke.

Comment: @user30598, leider war meine Antwort falsch, Dank noch einmal an Hagen. Ich hoffe, dass sie jetzt richtig und Dir immer noch klar ist :)

Comment: @user30598 ich denke übrigens, dass der Satz eher etwas wie „der Sprecher verleiht den Gefühlen durch Mimik, Stimmlage und Gestik Ausdruck“ wäre.

Comment: Ja , ganz genau , das Subjekt kann nicht der Ausdruck sein . Ich habe Ihnen über der Aktivsatz schon erzählt . Und Ausdruck hier bedeutet wie ( Wichtigkeit ) .

Comment: @user30598: Im Satz in der Frage ist ohne Zweifel *Ausdruck* das Subjekt. Dass das nicht der ganze Satz ist, ist nur eine Vermutung und ändert nichts. Und bitte das nächste Mal solche Sätze in der Frage, nicht im Titel.

Comment: O.k , alles klar , mache ich .

Comment: @user30598: Es wurde schon gesagt: bitte vor Satzzeichen, wie z.B. Kommas oder Punkte, **keine Leerzeichen**. Dein Satz `O.k , alles klar , ` usw. sollte sein: `O.k., alles klar, ` usw.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Erklärung . Schönen Tag noch !

Comment: @user30598: Du machst es schon wieder! Ist das mit Absicht?

Comment: Ich bitte um Verzeihung, vielleicht habe ich Ihre Erklärung nicht völlig verstanden, weil mein Deutsch noch nicht so gut ist, aber ich glaube, dass ich es endlich kapiert habe. Also, keine Leerzeichen vor Satzzeichen, sondern nach dem Satzzeichen. Und ich möchte mich bei Ihnen für dieses Versäumnis entschuldigen. Es hat mit Absicht nichts zu tun.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Kommentare zur Frage bitte als Kommentare zur Frage, nicht zu einer Antwort ;)